# Finding Height of text in PDF c#

Tags: c#, itext

I am working on developing pdf based files.for pdf files creation i am using itextsharp. In that i am having trouble for finding the height of the text, i extract the LocationTextExtractionStrategy class for finding the size of the text, but the corresponding Y and Y1 are showing the same result. i am attaching code for your reference.

```
public class LocationTextExtractionStrategyWithPosition : LocationTextExtractionStrategy
{
    private readonly List<TextChunk> locationalResult = new List<TextChunk>();

    private readonly ITextChunkLocationStrategy tclStrat;

    public LocationTextExtractionStrategyWithPosition() : this(new TextChunkLocationStrategyDefaultImp())
    {
    }

    public LocationTextExtractionStrategyWithPosition(ITextChunkLocationStrategy strat)
    {
        tclStrat = strat;
    }

    private bool StartsWithSpace(string str)
    {
        if (str.Length == 0) return false;
        return str[0] == ' ';
    }

    private bool EndsWithSpace(string str)
    {
        if (str.Length == 0) return false;
        return str[str.Length - 1] == ' ';
    }

    private List<TextChunk> filterTextChunks(List<TextChunk> textChunks, ITextChunkFilter filter)
    {
        if (filter == null)
        {
            return textChunks;
        }

        var filtered = new List<TextChunk>();

        foreach (var textChunk in textChunks)
        {
            if (filter.Accept(textChunk))
            {
                filtered.Add(textChunk);
            }
        }

        return filtered;
    }

    public override void RenderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo)
    {
        LineSegment segment = renderInfo.GetBaseline();
        if (renderInfo.GetRise() != 0)
        { 
            Matrix riseOffsetTransform = new Matrix(0, -renderInfo.GetRise());
            segment = segment.TransformBy(riseOffsetTransform);
        }
        TextChunk tc = new TextChunk(renderInfo.GetText(), tclStrat.CreateLocation(renderInfo, segment));
        locationalResult.Add(tc);
    }

    public IList<TextLocation> GetLocations()
    {
        var filteredTextChunks = filterTextChunks(locationalResult, null);
        filteredTextChunks.Sort();

        TextChunk lastChunk = null;

        var textLocations = new List<TextLocation>();

        foreach (var chunk in filteredTextChunks)
        {
                textLocations.Add(new TextLocation
                {
                    Text = chunk.Text,
                    X = chunk.Location.StartLocation[0],
                    Y = chunk.Location.StartLocation[1],
                    X1 = chunk.Location.EndLocation[0],
                    Y1 = chunk.Location.EndLocation[1]
                });

            lastChunk = chunk;
        }

        //now find the location(s) with the given texts
        return textLocations;
    }
}

public class TextLocation
{
    public float X { get; set; }
    public float Y { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }
    public float X1 { get; set; }
    public float Y1 { get; set; }
}
```

Here my screenshot for your reference

[image: Here my screenshot for your referece]

Comment: Well, for horizontal text start and end quite obviously are at the same height, aren't they?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the implementation of `ITextChunkLocation` used in `chunk.Location` only contains information relating to the start and end of the chunk on the baseline. Thus, for horizontal text start and end are at the same height.

If you want to also keep tabs on other detail like the height, you should create another implementation of `ITextChunkLocation` that also stores those properties of the original text render information. Then implement `ITextChunkLocationStrategy` for your location class and use it in the constructor of your `LocationTextExtractionStrategyWithPosition`.

Comment: thank you so much mr.mkl!!!!! that  was helped a lot i tried what u said, and now i got my result